# Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Username'. The argument is null or empty

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a Central server where all the Server Details and its credentials are stored. I am fetching the Server Name and its login and password using a query and fetching results from remote SQL servers. I am able to fetch the result but it throws an error in Powershell output.

PS Script:

```js
$computers=Get-Content "$MyDir\$Role-serverlist.txt";
ForEach($a in $computers)
{
$Login= (Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Server -Username "abc" -Password "defg" -Database $Database -Query "select username")
$Password=(Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Server -Username "abc" -Password "defg" -Database $Database -Query "select Password")

$Result = (Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $a -Username "$Login" -Password "$Password" -Database master -Query "$Query")
 $Result
}
```

Error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Username'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
> At E:\Query.ps1:100 char:56
> + $result =(Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "$a" -Username "$Login" -Password "$Pass ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is on  
$Result = (Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $a **-Username "$Login"** -Password "$Password" -Database master -Query "$Query") 
**"$Login" : may be null** 

Whatever comes within " " , powershell consider it as variable not string.